# Hosting a Web Application

Tags: heroku, web-applications, web, dns, hosting

I have a quick question regarding hosting web applications. I've recently started getting into hacking so I just wanted to understand them a little more.

I am aware that to host websites you need to pay for a domain name, as well as a hosting service. So let's say you buy a domain from GoDaddy, and then you buy hosting from Dreamhost.

Let's say I'm making a web application in Node.js, then I need to buy a cloud platform such as heroku, correct?

So do I need to buy a domain, hosting service, AND a cloud platform in order to launch a web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud hosting is just another kind of hosting versus stuff like Dreamhost.

You likely can't run something like Node.js on Dreamhost's shared hosting, but you could on one of their VPS/dedicated servers. Heroku's just easier for that sort of thing. You'd in most cases pick **either** Dreamhost *or* Heroku, not both.

Comment: Thanks! So if I were to make a personal website with just some links and info about me, I'd use something like Dreamhost; if I were to have a website where I process some data and use API's to achieve some sort of functionality, I'd use Heroku?

Let's say I have an app called myWebApp. Do I need to buy myWebApp.com from GoDaddy still, or does Heroku do that for me?

Comment: @KevinKim You could host a personal website on Heroku just fine. You could process data and use APIs on Dreamhost using any of their supported languages (I know they support PHP). Again, cloud hosting isn't anything magic - it's just another type of hosting. I don't know if Heroku sells domain names, but you can buy them from any registrar. I prefer Namecheap over GoDaddy. You don't (and some say shouldn't) have to buy a domain from your host.